# How to click to the selected item then navigate to the corresponding component in p-dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Please see the [p-dropdown](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown)
I modified the class `City` which now has one more property `url`. This property indicates the path of a component.

I have created the dropdown as

```
interface City {
    name: string;
    code: string;
    url:  string;
}

export class DropdownDemo {

cities: City[];

selectedCity: City;

constructor() {
    this.cities = [
        {name: 'New York', code: 'NY', url: 'app/ny'},
        {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM', url: 'app/rm'},
        {name: 'Washington DC', code: 'DC', url: 'app/dc'},
        {name: 'Houston', code: 'HT', url: 'app/ht'},
        {name: 'Paris', code: 'PR', url: 'app/pr'}
        ];
   }
}
```

The dropdown menu is in a navbar. The html page:

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse>
    <ui class="narbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nar-item>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/ny">NY</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nar-item>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/rm">RM</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nar-item>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/dc">DC</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nar-item>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/ht">HT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nar-item>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/pr">
                 <p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" 
           optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
           </a>
         </li>
      </ui>
     </div>
```

The dropdown displays correctly. Now what I want is that if I click the dropdown menu item then it will go to the corresponding component. So I guess that maybe I have to bind `href` or `routerLink` somewhere. But I just don't know how?

**UPDATE:**

If I add a click event inside the `p-dropdown` element then navigating, the code seems working but the page is still on the component of the path `api/pr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can maybe use the onChange($event),

```
  <p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name" (onChange)="onChange($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

when a city is clicked you will recive all the data, then you can use

```
router.navigate(['xxxxx']);
```

to go to the page you want, but first you need to set up a router !

**Edit**:

you need to change this :

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/pr">
  <p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
</a>
```

to

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" 
           optionLabel="name" (onChange)="onChange($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

then in your ts file you need to create a new methode like this :

```
onChange(event) {
    console.log('event :' + event);
    console.log(event.value);
    router.navigate([event.value.url]); // something like that

}
```

Comment: I updated the question. The thing is router can work but it is still on the nav item component.

Comment: `<a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/pr"><a>`
Will always bring you to /api/pr
 onChange($event) allow you to get what city is pressed and do different things, like routing your app to an other page.
I think you have to implement some logic in your ts file

Comment: Yes, I think that it maybe the problem. It looks like `<a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/api/pr"><a>` overrides the `onChange($event)`. But not sure how to  deal with that.

Comment: I edited my answer ! (sry i'm new to stack :)

Comment: It works, thank you. I didn't think that I have to remove `a` element.

Comment: Nice ! to make a link you don't have to nessesary you <a></a> a lot of the time if you want to do something on a component you can go with a methode, and on your methode, route the user !